# orientdb oetl error / I want to have pokec data

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-etl

To configure the current pokec db ./oetl.sh I'm trying. However, the pipeline exit keeps occurring. I don't know what the problem is. Help me.The dburl is also a code that was well written but is now erased. I've tried all the settings, but they can't. If you do this, the data will be good, but it will not shut down automatically.

```
 {
  "config": {
    "parallel": true
  },
  "source": {
   "file": {
      "path": "/home/yuna/soc-pokec-profiles.txt",
      "lock" : true ,
      "encoding" : "UTF-8"
       }
    },
  "extractor": { "row": {} },
  "transformers": [
    { "csv": {"columns":["id","public","completion_percentage","gender","region","region2","last_login","registration","AGE","body","I_am_working_in_field","spoken_languages","hobbies","I_most_enjoy_good_food","pets","body_type","my_eyesight","eye_color","hair_color","hair_type","completed_level_of_education","favourite_color","relation_to_smoking","relation_to_alcohol","on_pokec_i_am_looking_for","love_is_for_me","relation_to_casual_sex","my_partner_should_be","marital_status","children","relation_to_children","I_like_movies","I_like_watching_movie","I_like_music","I_mostly_like_listening_to_music","the_idea_of_good_evening","I_like_specialties_from_kitchen","fun","I_am_going_to_concerts","my_active_sports","my_passive_sports","profession","I_like_books","life_style","music","cars","politics","relationships","art_culture","hobbies_interests","science_technologies","computers_internet","education","sport","movies","travelling","health","companies_brands","more"],"separator": "/t","nullValue": "NULL"} },
    { "vertex": { "class": "Profile"} },
    {"field":
      { "fieldName" : "id",
        "expression" : "id.prefix('P')"
      }
    },
    {"field":
      { "fieldNames" : 
      ["region2","body","I_am_working_in_field","spoken_languages","hobbies","I_most_enjoy_good_food","pets","body_type","my_eyesight","eye_color","hair_color","hair_type","completed_level_of_education","favourite_color","relation_to_smoking","relation_to_alcohol","on_pokec_i_am_looking_for","love_is_for_me","relation_to_casual_sex","my_partner_should_be","marital_status","children","relation_to_children","I_like_movies","I_like_watching_movie","I_like_music","I_mostly_like_listening_to_music","the_idea_of_good_evening","I_like_specialties_from_kitchen","fun","I_am_going_to_concerts","my_active_sports","my_passive_sports","profession","I_like_books","life_style","music","cars","politics","relationships","art_culture","hobbies_interests","science_technologies","computers_internet","education","sport","movies","travelling","health","companies_brands","more"],
       "operation": "remove"
      }
    }
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
       "dbURL": "",
       "dbType": "graph",
       "wal": false,
       "batchCommit": 10000,
       "useLightweightEdges" : true,
       "dbAutoCreateProperties": true,
       "classes": [
         {"name": "Profile", "extends": "V", "clusters": 3},
         {"name": "Relation", "extends": "E"}
       ], "indexes": [
         {"class":"Profile", "fields":["id:string"], "type":"UNIQUE" }
       ],
       "settings": {
       }
    }
  }
```